# why Imported fbx tga from UE4 look black?

Tags: texturing, materials, import, unreal-engine

why Imported fbx tga from UE4 look black? I'm a novice, and New to texturing and materials, so Please help me finding what am I doing wrong.

I exported a static mesh from ue4 then the textures as tga. I replaced one of the placeholder textures for the tgs, but everything looks gray or black.

Can somebody teach me how to apply tga textures properly in this case?

[image: Screenshot]

[Blender file attachment](https://files.fm/u/p7mwr2uz)

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this issue because texture parameters in the materials are set wrong, instead of using the texture as diffuse color it is used as normal value.

To fix that, in each texture enable **Color** influence and disable **Normal** influence on the Geometry

[image]

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks a lot. It can be difficult to find good answers to questions that are extremely basic. But those questions can be the most frustrating.